# How do if all posts has this category ID then do this

Tags: php, posts, loop

I need a wordpress function that search all the posts inside my website and if one or multiple posts have the category ID (example 25) `echo "yes"`, `else echo "no"`

I was trying to do:

```
if ( has_category(25) ) {
   echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "NO OK";
}
```

But dont work

EDIT: My goal is to show comments section only if the category is "25" the other posts has not to show comments section

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_category( $id )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category/), the object it returns includes a count of posts contained in this category.

To build on your example, this would be:

```
$my_category = get_category( '25' );

if ( 1 <= $my_category->category_count ) {
   echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "NO OK";
}
```

Comment: thanks, but work if the category is a parent and all the posts are child's? because it return me "NO OK", just to know

Comment: if is not possible, How can I inlcude the childs IDs categories?

Comment: I have updated my answer with my goal

Comment: I have tried to put a child category but anyway it return me "OK" even if another post in have a different category.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I found a solution: 
This can be:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_comments_specific_categories' );

function remove_comments_specific_categories() {
    if ( !in_category( '1126' ) && !in_category( '1124' ) && !in_category( '35' ) && !in_category( '1050' ) && !in_category( '33' ) && !in_category( '1077' ) && !in_category( '39' ) && !in_category( '32' ) && !in_category( '32' ) && !in_category( '27' ) && !in_category( '38' )) {
        ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            #comments {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
        <?php
    }
}
```